# How can I create a diffuse map that looks and reacts like a Vertex Weight map?

Tags: weight-painting, dynamic-paint

Goal: Create a animation of the gradient pressure map on the top of a seat as the user sits down.

What I've tried: Dynamic painting works well, but I can't figure out how to get the gradient colors along the borders of the paint similar to the surface type:"weight" setting in dynamic painting.

It would be perfect if I could figure out how to create a series of images that look like the vertex weight paint mode with surface type:"weight" setting in dynamic painting to use as a diffuse shader.

Comment: Dynamic paint supports baking to an image sequence, which you could then use to texture the seat.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

## Image sequence

1. With the *canvas* object selected, set the format to *image*, then set the UV map and output path/format:

   [image]
2. Bake the image sequence, then load it into your material with an image node:

   [image]

**Result:**

[image]

## Vertex paint:

You can also bake to vertex colors and use a node setup like this, using an attribute node to get the vertex color:

[image]